# Summing $1,3,5,\ldots$

Tags: recurrence-relation

I solved a recurrence to get the formula $T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}2i+1$ for $k = \frac{n-1}{2}$, namely

$$ T(n) = 1 + 3 + \dots + (n-4) + (n-2) + n, $$

but I'm not sure how to finish off the problem by writing the summation and solving for the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

- $1 = 1$
- $1 + 3 = 4$
- $1 + 3 + 5 = 9$
- $1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16$
- $1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25$

Can you recognize the sequence $1,4,9,16,25$?

To prove the corresponding formula, use the following idea:
$$
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = \frac{1+7}{2} + \frac{3+5}{2} + \frac{5+3}{2} + \frac{7+1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If we define $\begin{cases} S(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i \\ T(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (2i+1)\\ U(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (2i)\end{cases}$.

1. Find (or recall) a closed-form expression of $S(n)$
2. Express $U$ in terms of $S$ then derive a closed-form solution for $U$
3. Conclude using the fact that $S(n)=T(n)+U(n)$.